# Config file for LXDE's PCManFM

Tags: arch-linux, file-management, lxde

I'm looking for the configuration file for [PCManFM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCManFM), the default file manager for LXDE.

Specifically, I want to change PCManFM's desktop directory which defaults to `~/Desktop/`.

I'm using PCManFM version 1.2.5 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration file is at `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/desktop-items-0.conf`.

To change the desktop folder, change the setting `folder`.

This is how my file looks:

```
[*]
wallpaper_mode=crop
wallpaper_common=1
wallpaper=/home/mb/images/simple_shapes.png
desktop_bg=#000000
desktop_fg=#ffffff
desktop_shadow=#000000
desktop_font=Sans 12
folder=/home/mb/superSpecialDir
show_wm_menu=0
sort=mtime;ascending;
show_documents=0
show_trash=1
show_mounts=0
```